# Date.table solution to create cumulative weekly averages based on condition

Tags: r, data.table

I have daily measures of x data. Each unique ID (a, b) has multiple rows of data. For each unique ID, I want to calculate weekly averages for weeks 1-2 and cumulative weekly averages for weeks3 - (end date) of the x data that falls within Start.date and End.date. Each weekly average would be a new column.

The following code calculates weekly averages by creating a week variable for each unique ID:

```
dcast(dat[,
                  week := floor(difftime(Date, Start.date, units = "weeks")) + 1,
                  by = .(ID)][,
                              .(weekly_mean = mean(x)),
                              by = .(ID, week)],
      ID ~ paste("week", week, sep = "_"),
      value.var = "weekly_mean")
```

Could I create these cumulative weekly averages based off the existing weekly averages? If so, can I eventually remove the weekly averages for weeks3-(end date) once I have the cumulative average columns?

How I want the resulting dataset to look:

```
Date x Start.Date End.Date ID. Week_1 Week_2 Week_3_cum Week_4_cum ...
```

Some data:

```
dat <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1104969600, 1105056000, 
1105142400, 1105228800, 1105315200, 1105401600, 1105488000, 1105574400, 
1105660800, 1105747200, 1105833600, 1105920000, 1106006400, 1106092800, 
1106179200, 1106265600, 1106352000, 1106438400, 1106524800, 1106611200, 
1106697600, 1106784000, 1106870400, 1106956800, 1107043200, 1107129600, 
1107216000, 1107302400, 1107388800, 1107475200, 1107561600, 1107648000, 
1107734400, 1107820800, 1107907200, 1107993600, 1108080000, 1108166400, 
1108252800, 1108339200, 1108425600, 1108512000, 1108598400, 1108684800, 
1108771200, 1108857600, 1108944000, 1109030400, 1109116800, 1109203200, 
1109289600, 1109376000, 1109462400, 1109548800, 1104969600, 1105056000, 
1105142400, 1105228800, 1105315200, 1105401600, 1105488000, 1105574400, 
1105660800, 1105747200, 1105833600, 1105920000, 1106006400, 1106092800, 
1106179200, 1106265600, 1106352000, 1106438400, 1106524800, 1106611200, 
1106697600, 1106784000, 1106870400, 1106956800, 1107043200, 1107129600, 
1107216000, 1107302400, 1107388800, 1107475200, 1107561600, 1107648000, 
1107734400, 1107820800, 1107907200, 1107993600, 1108080000, 1108166400, 
1108252800, 1108339200, 1108425600, 1108512000, 1108598400, 1108684800, 
1108771200, 1108857600, 1108944000, 1109030400, 1109116800, 1109203200, 
1109289600, 1109376000, 1109462400, 1109548800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), x = c(9.5, 9.4, 9.7, 10.11, 11.11, 
12.11, 13.11, 14.11, 15.11, 10.11, 11.11, 12.11, 13.11, 14.11, 
15.11, 9.5, 9.4, 9.7, 10.11, 11.11, 12.11, 13.11, 14.11, 15.11, 
10.11, 11.11, 12.11, 13.11, 14.11, 15.11, 9.5, 9.4, 9.7, 10.11, 
11.11, 12.11, 13.11, 14.11, 15.11, 10.11, 11.11, 12.11, 13.11, 
14.11, 15.11, 9.5, 9.4, 9.7, 10.11, 11.11, 12.11, 13.11, 14.11, 
15.11, 10.11, 11.11, 12.11, 13.11, 14.11, 15.11, 9.5, 9.4, 9.7, 
10.11, 11.11, 12.11, 13.11, 14.11, 15.11, 10.11, 11.11, 12.11, 
13.11, 14.11, 15.11, 9.5, 9.4, 9.7, 10.11, 11.11, 12.11, 13.11, 
14.11, 15.11, 10.11, 11.11, 12.11, 13.11, 14.11, 15.11, 9.5, 
9.4, 9.7, 10.11, 11.11, 12.11, 13.11, 14.11, 15.11, 16.11, 17.11, 
18.11, 19.11, 20.11, 21.11, 22.11, 23.11, 24.11), Start.Date = structure(c(1104969600, 
1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 
1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 
1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 
1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 
1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 
1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 
1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 
1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 
1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104969600, 1104883200, 
1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 
1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 
1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 
1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 
1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 
1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 
1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 
1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 
1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200, 1104883200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), End.Date = structure(c(1109635200, 
1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 
1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 
1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 
1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 
1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 
1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 
1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 
1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 
1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109635200, 1109548800, 
1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 
1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 
1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 
1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 
1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 
1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 
1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 
1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 
1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800, 1109548800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), ID = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b")), row.names = c(NA, 
-108L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

setDT(dat)
```

Comment: It's not crystal clear what you mean ... can you include specific expected output (i.e., numbers) given this sample data? Also, "week" can start/end on different days, based on locale (and preference); how do you define "week"? (Or are your weeks already defined by unique ranges of `Start.date` and `End.date`?)

Comment: I updated my post to include what I want the resulting columns would look like.. wasn't able to include specific numbers as I'm not sure how to complete this in R, but I included how each week would be defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is an approach.

Note, while you mention the cumulative mean, `cummean()` means something in R. `cummean()` returns a vector the same length as the input and therefore does not aggregate into a single value. So the steps are:

1. Aggregate to find the count of each group and the `sum(O3)`
2. For the first two weeks, simply find the mean of each week.
3. For the remaining weeks, use the `cumsum` to calculate a running average.
4. `dcast` into your inteded results.

```r
library(data.table)

dat[,week:= floor(difftime(AQ.Date, Start.Date, uni = "weeks")) + 1, by = ID]

ans = dat[,
    .(.N, weekly_sum = sum(O3)),
    by = .(ID, week)
    ][, 
      {
        lgl_ind = week < 3
        first_weeks = which(lgl_ind)
        last_weeks = which(!lgl_ind)
        
        out = numeric(length(week))
        out[first_weeks] = weekly_sum[first_weeks] / N[first_weeks]
        out[last_weeks] = cumsum(weekly_sum[last_weeks]) / cumsum(N[last_weeks])
        
        calc_type = c(rep('mean', length(first_weeks)),
                      rep('cummean', length(last_weeks)))
        
        list(week, weekly_mean = out, calc_type)
      },
      by = ID]  

ans
#>         ID       week weekly_mean calc_type
#>     <char> <difftime>       <num>    <char>
#>  1:      a    1 weeks    10.72000      mean
#>  2:      a    2 weeks    12.82429      mean
#>  3:      a    3 weeks    11.00571   cummean
#>  4:      a    4 weeks    11.84357   cummean
#>  5:      a    5 weeks    11.65952   cummean
#>  6:      a    6 weeks    11.87929   cummean
#>  7:      a    7 weeks    11.81886   cummean
#>  8:      a    8 weeks    11.98025   cummean
#>  9:      b    1 weeks    12.61000      mean
#> 10:      b    2 weeks    10.72000      mean
#> 11:      b    3 weeks    12.82429   cummean
#> 12:      b    4 weeks    11.91500   cummean
#> 13:      b    5 weeks    12.17048   cummean
#> 14:      b    6 weeks    11.95071   cummean
#> 15:      b    7 weeks    12.58257   cummean
#> 16:      b    8 weeks    13.90366   cummean

dcast(ans,
      ID ~ paste("week", week,calc_type,  sep = "_"),
      value.var = 'weekly_mean')
#>        ID week_1_mean week_2_mean week_3_cummean week_4_cummean week_5_cummean
#>    <char>       <num>       <num>          <num>          <num>          <num>
#> 1:      a       10.72    12.82429       11.00571       11.84357       11.65952
#> 2:      b       12.61    10.72000       12.82429       11.91500       12.17048
#>    week_6_cummean week_7_cummean week_8_cummean
#>             <num>          <num>          <num>
#> 1:       11.87929       11.81886       11.98025
#> 2:       11.95071       12.58257       13.90366
```

Comment: This solution is literally 15 minutes faster than how long my initial solution takes to run (on the actual dataset, not the sample data). I did it manually for each week, only grouping by ID. Thank you. I'm having a hard time learning the syntax for data.table and am still not sure I'm understanding each line in your solution. Which resource would you recommend for learning data.table?

Comment: It took time for me to learn as well. The most interesting part of [tag:data.table] is that learning base really helps. The code in between the ```{...}``` is just base. When we provide a list in the curly expression, ```data.table``` will be able to handle it well. As far as what to start with, other than base, I think all of the vignettes of data.table do a very good job.

Comment: What is ".N" before weekly_sum?

Comment: See ```?.N```  - a lot o f special symbols have help file information. To directly answer, ```.N``` is the number of items in each group which makes it similar to [tag:dplyr] ```n()```

Answer (score 1):

When aggregating on different date ranges, my perferred approach is to *aggregate in a non-equi join*.

Thus, the code to aggregate is simply:

```
dat[date_ranges, on = .(ID, AQ.Date >= beg, AQ.Date <= end), 
    .(week_name, weekly_mean = mean(O3)), by = .EACHI]
```

Or, with subsequent reshaping as requested by the OP:

```
dcast(dat[date_ranges, on = .(ID, AQ.Date >= beg, AQ.Date <= end), 
          .(week_name, weekly_mean = mean(O3)), by = .EACHI],
      ID ~ week_name, value.var = "weekly_mean")
```

> ```
>    ID week_1   week_2   week_3 weeks_3_4 weeks_3_5 weeks_3_6 weeks_3_7 weeks_3_8
> 1:  a  10.72 12.82429 11.00571  11.84357  11.65952  11.87929  11.81886  11.98025
> 2:  b  12.61 10.72000 12.82429  11.91500  12.17048  11.95071  12.58257  13.90366
> ```

Note that `week_name` indicates which weeks are included in the aggregate.

The challenge is to create `date_ranges` in the specific way requested by the OP.

This is accomplished by

```
# coerce POSIXct datetimes to integer dates to allow for simplified arithmetic on dates
cols <- stringr::str_subset(names(dat), "Date")
dat[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.IDate), .SDcols = cols]

# create data.table of weekly date ranges by ID
cumul_after_week <- 3L
date_ranges <- dat[, {
  from <- first(Start.Date)
  to <- first(End.Date)
  beg <- seq(from, to, 7L)
  end <- pmin(beg + 6L, to)
  beg[which(seq_along(beg) > cumul_after_week)] <- beg[cumul_after_week]
  week <- seq_along(beg)
  week_name <- fifelse(week <= cumul_after_week, 
                     sprintf("week_%i", week), 
                     sprintf("weeks_%i_%i", cumul_after_week, week))
  list(week_name = week_name, beg = beg, end = end)
}, by = ID]
```

Now, `date_ranges` contains all periods to aggregate on plus descriptive week names (or period names to be precise):

> ```
> date_ranges
>     ID week_name        beg        end
>  1:  a    week_1 2005-01-06 2005-01-12
>  2:  a    week_2 2005-01-13 2005-01-19
>  3:  a    week_3 2005-01-20 2005-01-26
>  4:  a weeks_3_4 2005-01-20 2005-02-02
>  5:  a weeks_3_5 2005-01-20 2005-02-09
>  6:  a weeks_3_6 2005-01-20 2005-02-16
>  7:  a weeks_3_7 2005-01-20 2005-02-23
>  8:  a weeks_3_8 2005-01-20 2005-03-01
>  9:  b    week_1 2005-01-05 2005-01-11
> 10:  b    week_2 2005-01-12 2005-01-18
> 11:  b    week_3 2005-01-19 2005-01-25
> 12:  b weeks_3_4 2005-01-19 2005-02-01
> 13:  b weeks_3_5 2005-01-19 2005-02-08
> 14:  b weeks_3_6 2005-01-19 2005-02-15
> 15:  b weeks_3_7 2005-01-19 2005-02-22
> 16:  b weeks_3_8 2005-01-19 2005-02-28
> ```

Note that week 3 is still the aggregate of a single week according to OP's definition

> Week_3_cum: mean(O3) for Start.date + 14 <= AQ.Date < Start.date + 21

so it is marked as a single week.

#### Some explanations

- `Start.Date` and `End.Date`, resp. are identical within each `ID` group. `first(Start.Date)` and `first(End.Date)`, resp.,  are used to pick a single value instead of the whole vector for the subsequent call to `seq()`.
- `pmin()` is used in `end <- pmin(beg + 6L, to)` to ensure that the last week in each range uses the correct `End.Date` in case there are less than 7 days.
- `beg[which(seq_along(beg) > cumul_after_week)] <- beg[cumul_after_week]` replaces the continuously increasing `beg` dates by the constant start date for the "cumulative weekly averages" as requested by the OP. In case the sequence of periods is shorter than the requested start of "cumulation", `which(seq_along(beg) > cumul_after_week)` returns an empty vector and nothing is replaced.

This approach is quite flexible because `cumul_after_week` can be changed easily. With

```
cumul_after_week <- 1L
```

`date_ranges` becomes

> ```
>     ID week_name        beg        end
>  1:  a    week_1 2005-01-06 2005-01-12
>  2:  a weeks_1_2 2005-01-06 2005-01-19
>  3:  a weeks_1_3 2005-01-06 2005-01-26
>  4:  a weeks_1_4 2005-01-06 2005-02-02
>  5:  a weeks_1_5 2005-01-06 2005-02-09
>  6:  a weeks_1_6 2005-01-06 2005-02-16
>  7:  a weeks_1_7 2005-01-06 2005-02-23
>  8:  a weeks_1_8 2005-01-06 2005-03-01
>  9:  b    week_1 2005-01-05 2005-01-11
> 10:  b weeks_1_2 2005-01-05 2005-01-18
> 11:  b weeks_1_3 2005-01-05 2005-01-25
> 12:  b weeks_1_4 2005-01-05 2005-02-01
> 13:  b weeks_1_5 2005-01-05 2005-02-08
> 14:  b weeks_1_6 2005-01-05 2005-02-15
> 15:  b weeks_1_7 2005-01-05 2005-02-22
> 16:  b weeks_1_8 2005-01-05 2005-02-28
> ```

and with

```
cumul_after_week <- 5L
```

`date_ranges` becomes

> ```
>     ID week_name        beg        end
>  1:  a    week_1 2005-01-06 2005-01-12
>  2:  a    week_2 2005-01-13 2005-01-19
>  3:  a    week_3 2005-01-20 2005-01-26
>  4:  a    week_4 2005-01-27 2005-02-02
>  5:  a    week_5 2005-02-03 2005-02-09
>  6:  a weeks_5_6 2005-02-03 2005-02-16
>  7:  a weeks_5_7 2005-02-03 2005-02-23
>  8:  a weeks_5_8 2005-02-03 2005-03-01
>  9:  b    week_1 2005-01-05 2005-01-11
> 10:  b    week_2 2005-01-12 2005-01-18
> 11:  b    week_3 2005-01-19 2005-01-25
> 12:  b    week_4 2005-01-26 2005-02-01
> 13:  b    week_5 2005-02-02 2005-02-08
> 14:  b weeks_5_6 2005-02-02 2005-02-15
> 15:  b weeks_5_7 2005-02-02 2005-02-22
> 16:  b weeks_5_8 2005-02-02 2005-02-28
> ```